# Install Nginx Passenger Rails on Ubuntu Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I arrange the bug information at https://gist.github.com/poc7667/6068900

I follow the steps in the link , but not worked
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

The Failed message is passenger send "Internal server error"  "An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a handshake message in time."

you can check the detail log by picture
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23461380/QQ%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%961020724161628.png

Comment: helped me https://shivab.com/blog/nginx/2018/08/20/installing-and-configuration-of-nginx-web-reverse-proxy-server-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Try following the advice in [Debugging application startup problems](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems) on the Phusion Passenger wiki.